# Problemas insertando datos con php+mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas con una app php+mysql.
Trabajo con 2 tablas workgroup y people.
Este es el formulario de registro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO workgroup(name) VALUES(:gname)";
$query2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$query2->bindParam(':gname',$gname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2->execute();

$sql3="SELECT group_id FROM `workgroup` WHERE name=:gname";
$query3 = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
$query3->bindParam(':gname',$gname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query3->execute();




$sql="INSERT INTO people(fullname,username,email,password,group_id,admin)
VALUES(:fullname,:username,:email,:password,$sql3,1)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$query->bindParam(':fullname',$fullname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password',$hasedpassword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

En la tabla workgroup se insertan bien los datos, pero no en la de people. Me puede ayudar alguien?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack overflow en español. Como su nombre indica, es un foro en español, te agradeceremos que cambies tu pregunta a español para ayudarte.

Comment: que es lo que te inserta o que error te genera..

Comment: no me muestra ningún error, simplemente no inserta los datos, solo en 1 tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el resultado de tu sentencia `select` no lo estas guardando en una variable, y la variable que usas en tu segundo `insert` tiene el código sql para obtener el `group_id`

Lo que debes hacer es guardar en una variable el resultado de tu sentencia

> SELECT group_id FROM workgroup WHERE name=:gname

Y esa variable es la que debes usar en tu segundo insert, algo mas o menos así:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO workgroup(name) VALUES(:gname)";
$query2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$query2->bindParam(':gname',$gname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2->execute();

$sql3="SELECT group_id FROM `workgroup` WHERE name=:gname";
$query3 = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
$query3->bindParam(':gname',$gname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query3->execute();
//Los datos devueltos los convertimos en un array asociativo
$data = $query3->fetch(FETCH_ASSOC);
//Aquí guardamos el valor que trae el select
$group_id = $data['group_id '];

//Nota que en este query usamos la variable `$group_id`
$sql="INSERT INTO people(fullname,username,email,password,group_id,admin) VALUES(:fullname,:username,:email,:password,$group_id,1)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':fullname',$fullname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password',$hasedpassword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto!!

Answer (score 1):

El valor de `$sql3` es actualmente `"SELECT group_id FROM`workgroup`WHERE name=:gname"`
y es ese valor el que le pasas a la sentencia sql `$sql="INSERT INTO people(fullname,username,email,password,group_id,admin)
VALUES(:fullname,:username,:email,:password,$sql3,1)";` debes primero asignarle el valor que genera la query, en este caso el id, a una variable `$id` y esta variable cambiarla por $sql3 en la sentencia `$sql="INSERT INTO people(fullname,username,email,password,group_id,admin)
VALUES(:fullname,:username,:email,:password,$id,1)";`